# Linkedin share functionality bug - popup auto resizing

Tags: javascript, share, linkedin-api

When I go here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-plugin-generator

provide some URL (i.e. google.com), and click on the button, new window popup is opening with some weird behavior - window automatically changes it's own size:/

The same problem will happen when you open popup window manually using JavaScript, with LinkedIn share URL: https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com

Problem is in Chrome (Win7), but FF (Win7) works fine. Is there anyone who can reproduce it? And can suggest any solution how to fix this behavior?

---

EDIT:
It seems that LinkedIn has fixed this issue as can't reproduce anymore.

Comment: ive seen this happen before too. you might contact them.

Comment: I feel better I'm not alone. And good point - I've just added new topic in plugins forum: https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/share-button-weird-behavior-auto-resizing-popup

Comment: So the problem that you're having is the fact that the popup adjusts to fit it's contents (600px)? What is the behavior that you're expecting?

Comment: nope - the problem is, popup is decreasing it's size to sth about 100px width and 300px height.

Comment: just encountered this today, still deciding if this is a bug or not

Answer (score 0):

So, since LinkedIn has been acquired by Microsoft, the way sharing works has been entirely redone.

Your documentation link just goes to a blank page, it doesn't even 404 or error out.  Anyway, here is the new documentation link: **[Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**

All you should need to make this work is to use this as your URL:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Wouldn't it have been nice to have known that the URL and the API for sharing has changed entirely?  If you are interested in a regularly maintained github project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]